# Why is my mergeSort / shellSort slower than insertion sort

Tags: java, algorithm

I have an array of 100000 elements which i have filled with random numbers form 0-999999
this is my    **Merge sort** **code** :

```
private static void sortArray(int[] data, int low, int high)
{
    if ((high - low) >= 1)
    {
        int middle1 = (low + high) / 2;
        int middle2 = middle1 + 1;
        sortArray(data, low, middle1);
        sortArray(data, middle2, high);
        merge (data, low, middle1, middle2, high);
    }
}

private static void merge(int[] data, int left, int middle1,
                          int middle2, int right)
{
    int leftIndex = left;
    int rightIndex = middle2;
    int combinedIndex = left;
    int[] combined = new int[data.length];

    while (leftIndex <= middle1 && rightIndex <= right)
    {
        if (data[leftIndex] <= data[rightIndex]){
            combined[combinedIndex++] = data[leftIndex++];
        }
        else{
            combined[combinedIndex++] = data[rightIndex++];
        }
    }

    if (leftIndex == middle2){

        while (rightIndex <= right)
            combined[combinedIndex++] = data[rightIndex++];
    }
    else {
        while (leftIndex <= middle1)
            combined[combinedIndex++] = data[leftIndex++];
    }
    for (int i = left; i <= right; i++)
        data[i] = combined[i];

}
```

This is my `shellSort` code:

```
public static void shellSort(){

    int inner , outer , temp;
    int interval = 1;
    while(interval < arraysize/3){
        interval = interval*3+1;
    }
    while(interval > 0){
        for(outer = interval; outer<arraysize; outer++){
            inner = outer;
            temp = array[inner];
            while(inner > interval-1 && array[inner-interval] >= temp){
                array[inner] = array[inner-interval];
                inner = inner - interval;
            }
                array[inner] = temp;
        }
            interval = (interval-1)/3;
    }       
}
```

and this is my **insertionSort** :

```
  public  static void insertionSort(){

    for(int i = 1; i < arraysize; i++){

        int value = array[i];
        int index = i;
        while(index > 0 && value < array[index-1]){
            array[index] = array[index-1];
            index--;
        }
        array[index] = value;
    }
}
```

And this is the time code:

```
    start = System.nanoTime();
    shellSort();
    end = System.nanoTime();
    System.out.println("shellsort took " + (end-start) + " nanosecs");

    start = System.nanoTime();
    sortArray(array , 0 , arraysize-1);
    end = System.nanoTime();
    System.out.println("mergesort took " + (end-start) + " nanosecs");

    start = System.nanoTime();
    insertionSort();
    end = System.nanoTime();
    System.out.println("insertionsort took " + (end-start) + " nanosecs");
```

**Time :**
shellsort took 25301559 nanosecs
mergesort took 41976634024 nanosecs
insertionsort took 2337867 nanosecs

Comment: please post your array-filling code, or check in the debugger to make sure it contains what you expect.  The insertionsort time is suspiciously short, suggesting your array is not being filled properly.

Comment: Also, if your timing code is written exactly like above, you are insertionSort is applied to the data that is already sorted by merge sort, so I assume there's some missing code in there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the same scratch array (combined[]) every time instead of allocating a new one.

Also, it is not really plausible that insertionSort is that fast.  InsertionSort is very fast on data that is already sorted or all the same, so it's likely that you are resorting the output of the merge sort (what your timing code does as-is), or your array filling code is putting in all zeros or something.

Comment: here is the result after doing what you suggested :                         shellsort took 19959841 nanosecs
mergesort took 9977418 nanosecs
insertionsort took 2219300 nanosecs

Comment: thanks for pointing that out it did improved merge sort performance but insertion sort is much better

Comment: As I mentioned above, i think your data is broken

Answer (score 1):

Most likely because you are creating more objects and have redundant copies. I suggest you profile it to see where the most time is being spent.

Try implement it without creating such large arrays. Insertion sort doesn't create any.

BTW, `(low + high) / 2` can overflow.

I suggest using `(low + high) >>> 1` or `low + (high - low) / 2` instead.

Comment: i did what you suggested not much difference, results are same

Comment: @HussainYousuf can you post the version of your code where you did this?

Comment: private static void sortArray(int[] data, int low, int high)
  {  
  if ((high - low) >= 1) 
  {
  int middle1 = (low + high) >>> 1;
  int middle2 = middle1 + 1; 
  sortArray(data, low, middle1);
  sortArray(data, middle2, high);
  merge (data, low, middle1, middle2, high);  
  }
 }

Comment: also i made combinedarray global insted of allocating a new one

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT: Ah, yeah, a very good point made in a comment to your original question: your insertion sort is sorting the data that is already sorted. This is indeed supposed to be very fast, as all it takes is a single scan of the array.**

Shell sort's expected performance without some complex optimization on the number and size of gaps is about the same as insertion sort, which is on par with what your are seeing.

As for the mergesort, allocating a new huge array on every step, and then copying data over is what's killing you. You gotta rewrite it to do the merging in-place to see the performance of actual sorting.

Answer (score 0):

Algorithms have a Big-O complexity which gives you the estimated running time of an algorithm based on `N` many inputs

Here is a great site listing the time and size complexities for many different algorithms.

[Site](http://bigocheatsheet.com/) - http://bigocheatsheet.com/

```
              Best Case                        Worst Case

MergeSort          O(n log(n)) (Average)        O(n log(n)) (Average)   
ShellSort          O(n) (Good)                  O((nlog(n))^2) (Bad)   
InsertionSort      O(n) (Good)                  O(n ^ 2) (Bad)
```

Insertion and Shell have the potential to be faster but in most cases mergesort should be faster.